# How to toggle case for text in a file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to know the command that will convert upper-case characters to lower-case characters and lower-case characters to upper-case characters.

It has to work in the shell of Unix machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tr A-Za-z a-zA-Z
```

(unfortunately, ascii only)

Comment: Please can you elaborate more... i want to know the details syntax

Comment: Try to say man tr in your terminal. You will learn something new.

Comment: There is a command `tr` which maps character ranges to other character ranges (it reads standard input and writes to standard output). Here, we specified "from A to Z + from a to z" as a source range, "from a to z then from A to Z" as a destination range, so english letters are mapped to their case-inverted equivalents.

Comment: my file contents are HELLO sir...so i want output as hello SIR

Comment: That's exactly what you get for `tr A-Za-z a-zA-z < yourfile.txt`

Answer (score 3):

```
cat file1 | tr 'a-zA-Z' 'A-Za-z'
```

Comment: not working.. my file contents are HELLO sir...so i want output as hello SIR

Comment: @Amar Hmmmm... works fine for me.

Comment: @Amar I think I did :-).  `cat file1` gets the contents of file1, which are then piped to `tr`, which swaps upper and lower case, and then the output goes to STDOUT.  Was there something else that you wanted to do?

Comment: I got the answer.. I am still beginner.. so trying hard to learn.. expecting your kind cooperation

Comment: +1 except you don't need `cat`: `tr 'a-zA-Z' 'A-Za-z' < file1`

Comment: @glennjackman True.  I think that's what Anton said in the comments below his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe your file into perl with the answer provided here:

[Perl, using tr function to convert uppercase to lowercase and vice-versa at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608052/perl-using-tr-function-to-convert-uppercase-to-lowercase-and-vice-versa-at-the)

Comment: if ($fred =~ /\A[A-Z_]\w*\z/i) {
# Do nothing
} else {
print "The value of \$fred doesn't look like a Perl identifier name.\n";
}

How the expression in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

To get lowercase: `sed -i 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' somefilename`

To get uppercase: `sed -i 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/' somefilename`

Comment: I want to know 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/' how this syntax works?

Comment: `s/b/b/` replaces all occurrences of string a with string b. 
`\(` means the start of a chunk that will be used later.
`\)` means the end of a chunk.
`.*` is a regexp (regular expression) that matches 0 or more (i.e. any) characters. After the second `/`, the `\U` means uppercase, and the `\1` means the first chunk (called a backreference) from earlier in the expression.

Comment: can you simplify more about \1

Comment: sed processes its input one line at a time, so `.*` is a regexp that matches all characters in the line.  For more info on regular expressions, check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: I just realized that this doesn't answer the original question, simultaneously converting uppercase to lowercase and lowercase to uppercase.  See David's answer below for that.

Comment: yes.. david's answer works fine

Comment: Hi david, brian can you tell me how this expression will work in perl                      if ($fred =~ /\A[A-Z_]\w*\z/i) {
# Do nothing
} else {
print "The value of \$fred doesn't look like a Perl identifier name.\n";
}